# How do I remove the border on images in the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I created a Navigation bar and I am trying to add a logo (with hyperlink) and it has a border that pushes my navigation bar lower which makes it uneven to the other text on the navigation bar [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWt9.jpg).

```
<!--Navigation bar code-->
   .topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
    }
    .topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: cadetblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
    }
    .topnav a:hover {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  color: white;
    }
<!--Image css code-->
            img {
                width: 80px;
                height: 50px;
                float: left;
            }
<!--Html Navigation bar-->
<div class="topnav">
            <a href="Home.html"><img src="logo.png" href="Home.html"></a>
            <a href="Help.html">Help</a>
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact us</a>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing over there isn't a border, it is the `background-color` that appears on `hover`. You can remove it from the css:

```
<!--Navigation bar code-->
   .topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
    }
    .topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: cadetblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
    }
    .topnav a:hover {
  <!-- background-color: cadetblue;  REMOVE -->
  <!-- color: white;  REMOVE -->
    }
<!--Image css code-->
            img {
                width: 80px;
                height: 50px;
                float: left;
            }
<!--Html Navigation bar-->
<div class="topnav">
            <a href="Home.html"><img src="logo.png" href="Home.html"></a>
            <a href="Help.html">Help</a>
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact us</a>
          </div>
```

However, if you are willing to keep that effect, you can adjust the links with the same height of the logo (`50px`) and then it will be even.